# Как сделать вращающийся слайдер?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Возникла такая проблема. Пишу на ванильном `js`, нужен слайдер как нарисовал дизайнер с анимацией прокручивания. Анимацию сделал, а вот под размеры подогнать не могу. Либо боковые пиццы улетают за края, либо центральная очень маленькая. Не могу сделать в соответствии с картинкой, но нужен еще и адаптив, поэтому не могу использовать фиксированную ширину.[image: макет слайдера]
Выбрал для этих целей **tiny-slider**. Возможно перейти и на другой слайдер, просто мне показался он достаточно функциональным.

Моя недоделанная [версия](https://codepen.io/Kravchenko55/pen/ZEYwRvG).

```
let slider = tns({
  container: '.my-slider',
  items: 3,
  center: true,
  nav: false,
  speed: 1000,
  controlsContainer: "#slider-controls",
  // Только центральной кнопке класс
  onInit: () => document.querySelectorAll('.tns-slide-active')[1].classList.add('pizza-active'),
});
```

Comment: Правильнее было бы здесь разместить.